# WOW.js animations work on one server, copied to new server, and stop working

Tags: child-theme

http://bmadmin.staging.wpengine.com/lifetime-loan/
The animations don't work. (except for the cloud background, but that's hand coded rather than a function of Wow.js)

http://newbenchmark.wpengine.com/lifetime-loan/
The animations do work.

Active plugins are identical. Can anyone see something that perhaps I'm missing?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you mantaining your website yourself? It only took 1 key press, `F12`, to identify the problem and every programmer should be able to use that. It clearly states that there's a JS error on line 252 which starts the trail of problems with `wow.js`. **Also:** please use [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) for generic JS, plugin or other issues from now on because it has nothing to do with WordPress core which this site is about.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `new WOW().init();` long before *wow.min.js* has kicked in which causes the error because there's no such thing as `WOW()` when it hasn't loaded yet.

Just remove it from your template and copy it to your theme main JS file which should be loaded **after** vital your, 3rd party etc JS files are loaded. Also wrap it with `jQuery(window).load(function() { }` or `jQuery(window).ready(function() { }`. [Why or which one? Read here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396407/jquery-what-are-differences-between-document-ready-and-window-load)

Using  wrapped JS directly in template is a bad practice anyway and should only be used when it's absolutelty necessary.

Again, this question has nothing to do with WordPress core and should be asked in Stackoverflow, I'll get smack to the head from the community just for answering this. Know better next time.